# Range-Doppler Matrix Cells

Tags: signal-detection, radar, doppler

I am working on developing an understanding on range-gates and the size of each cell. I haven't had much luck in finding information in how the matrix in the image below is generated, so I have some questions regarding the image below.

.[image]

Let's say I have a range resolution of 50 meters. Would that mean that each bin is constructed around that? For example, the first bin for pulse 1 is the amount of time it takes for a pulse to return at 50 meters, the second bin at 100 meters, the third bin at 150 meters and so on?

Alternatively, I think I may be thinking of it incorrectly in regards to using the range resolution to build the bins after looking at the image below. There, the size of the bins is based on the bandwidth of the pulse. That image makes me think that I'd have to create the bins based on the bandwidths, with range resolution only mattering for returns within a single cell.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track in relating the bandwidth of the waveform to the size of the range gates (aka bins).

Lets first talk about how the term "resolution" is to be used. In a radar system, there may be multiple resolutions you can point to and is naturally an overloaded term. It's very easy (and quite common) for radar analysts and even designers to make mistakes that come from misuse of the term. When it comes to range resolution specifically, it can mean either:

1. The raw capability of the waveform being employed. For an arbitrary waveform of bandwidth $\beta$, the range resolution $\delta R$ it can achieve is given by the ubiquitous $\delta R = c/(2\beta)$. There are a few ways to derive this which we won't cover here.
2. The size of your range gate, which is determined by the sample rate used to capture the "fast-time" dimension of the matrix. This is seen in the figure you have, where a gate's width (in time), is given by the sampling period $T_s$.

When designing a radar system, there is typically some range resolution desired. A waveform is designed with bandwidth $\beta$ to meet the requirement. Since we wish to sample the waveform after it returns from a target(s), we must do so at the Nyquist rate. For *complex* waveforms, specifically those that are *analytic*, that minimum sample rate $f_s$  to avoid aliasing is $f_s = \beta$.

So you see here that the range bin size is given by the sampling period $T_s$, precisely because that is what was required to capture the waveform without aliasing. You now have the two "range resolutions":

$$\delta R = \frac{c}{2\beta} \tag{1}$$
$$\Delta R = \frac{cT_s}{2} = \frac{c}{2 f_s} = \frac{c}{2\beta} \tag{2}$$

Again, (1) is what the waveform is theoretially capable of achieving, while (2) is the established bin size due to the chosen sample rate. For the above equations, the two resolutions equal each other since we've chosen to sample exactly at the Nyquist rate and so $f_s = \beta = 1/T_s$.

In practical systems, you usually don't sample right at the Nyquist rate for various reasons. It's desirable to sample beyond Nyquist so that now we have $f_s > \beta$. In this case, the range bin $\Delta R < \delta R$ and is thus *finer* than what the waveform can achieve. This is good! We'll be able to better accommodate processed returns. It is the other way around that needs to be avoided.

To summarize, the size of the range bin and the bandwidth of the waveform are intimately related. The size of the range bin (2) should be **at the minimum equal to** or smaller (finer) than the range resolution achieved by the waveform (1). Thus, it is desirable to have a sample rate $f_s \ge\beta$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! It helped clarify some concepts I was confused about, and I can start on an initial implementation. Unfortunately my reputation isn't high enough to upvote the answer.

Comment: @Afromullet No worries! If you need further explanation on the Doppler dimension side of things, let us know.